# Inter-Process Communication Between JSF and Servlets

Tags: jsf, servlets, ipc

I have a JSF managed bean that is connecting to a database, but I want the connection to be accessible by several Java servlets.  Is there a way to allow servlets to communicate with JSF beans and vice versa?

PS-- I apologize in advance for this question being similar to [Static Methods for Communicating Between JSF Managed Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680833/static-methods-for-communicating-between-jsf-managed-beans).

I am currently putting static methods in my JSF managed bean so that my servlet can access the database connection.  So far, things seem to work.